# Limit Enterprise Search Center to show pages only

Tags: 2013, search, enterprise-search

We have a search box in the header of our publishing site that directs to our search site. How can I limit the results to be pages only? Right now it's showing lists, PDFs, etc.

I'm thinking it's to do with the result sources (screenshot below), but I can't seem to change them. Do I need to do this from central admin?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change them from Central Admin. However some of them are built-in and cannot be changed. All of them can be copied. There is menu appears when you hover over one of them. You can choose copy and SharePoint will open a new page for you to create a new result source. Once you have done this you can make it the default for that site or site collection. You can try using "contentclass:STS_ListItem_WebPageLibrary"  to just bring back pages.